# Wordpress permalink settings broken

Tags: wordpress, permalinks

When I choose /%postname%/ permalink it adds a base directory (home-2) to the link like 
Before:
site.com/?p=123
After:
site.com/home-2/page
I want it to just be site.com/page.

Update: I see now that all permalink options give me the same link site.com/home-2/page even if I choose Month and name or any other setting.
If I type in site.com/page it redirects to site.com/home-2/page

Comment: more detail about your environment would be really helpful in your question. i had the same issue, but i am on heroku. might not be your answer and probably why you have a -1 on your question.

Answer (score 0):

Select Custom structure, and then put `/%postname%/` in the input box. Also make sure you don't have anything in the category or tag base input boxes under "Optional". Click save and see if that fixes your issue.

Comment: Tnx for reply. That was the first thing I tried. ;) It doesn't work. still same problem.

Comment: Hmmm. Do you have a page or a post called Home-2 created? Or even a category created in that name? If so, delete that. Also check to see if your pages don't have any parent pages.  Then try again.

Comment: No Home-2 anywhere. A parent page would create that problem? if so how would I fix?

Answer (score 0):

I solved this issue for myself: I was running MAMP locally for wordpress. However, I had NGINX in the Procfile (not apache clearly; that's the A in MAMP). I also was running HHVM on heroku and PHP (the P in MAMP) locally. once i changed my composer.json to:

```
{ "require": { "php": "^5.5.12" } }
```

and my Procfile to:

```
web: vendor/bin/heroku-php-apache2
```

and redeployed, `/%postname%/` permalinks worked!

In hindsight, if I was paying attention to this: http://12factor.net/dev-prod-parity, I would have resolved this a lot sooner.